# Can't animate balls on canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas

Trying to animate some balls, that appear with an interval on canvas.

Balls do appear every n* seconds, but I can't make them move :c

What am I doing wrong?

https://jsbin.com/mexofuz/26/edit?js,output

```
function Ball(){
    this.X = 50;
    this.Y = 50;
    this.radius = Math.floor(Math.random()*(30-10)+10);
    this.color = getRandomColor();
    this.dx = Math.floor(Math.random()*(20-10)+10);
    this.dy = Math.floor(Math.random()*(20-10)+10);
}
Ball.prototype.draw = function(){
    context.fillStyle = this.color;
    context.beginPath();
    context.arc(this.X, this.Y, this.radius, 0, Math.PI*2, true);
    context.closePath();
    context.fill();   
}
Ball.prototype.animate = function(){
  if(this.X<0 || this.X>(w-this.radius)) this.dx=-this.dx; 
  if(this.Y<0 || this.Y>(h-this.radius)) this.dy=-this.dy;
  this.X+=this.dx;
  this.Y+=this.dy;
}

var balls = [];

function render() {
    context.fillStyle = "white";
    context.fillRect(0, 0, w, h);
    for(var i = 1;i<=20;i++){
      balls[i] = new Ball();
      setTimeout(Ball.prototype.draw.bind(this.balls[i]), 5000 * i);
   // Ball.prototype.animate.bind(this.balls[i]);
      if (balls[i].X < 0 || balls[i].X > w-balls[i].radius) {
        balls[i].dx = -balls[i].dx;
      }

      if (balls[i].Y < 0 || balls[i].Y > h-balls[i].radius) {
        balls[i].dy = -balls[i].dy;
      }
        balls[i].x += balls[i].dx
        balls[i].y += balls[i].dy
 }
  console.log(balls);
}
render();
```

Comment: because every time you loop through `render`, you create all the balls from scratch again. try moving `balls[i] = new Ball();` *outside* of `render`

Comment: What are you expecting to happen - the balls to bounce around? You have no event loop, just timeouts every 5 seconds. You need to be processing a couple of times each second (30 times or so = 30fps). Check out http://www.playmycode.com/blog/2011/08/building-a-game-mainloop-in-javascript/ as an example

Answer (score 0):

You need to do two things - firstly, update your 'ball' position. At the moment you just do this once, you need to place it inside of a setInterval or another method of updating several times a second. Secondly you need to redraw the canvas each time the balls move (once per update is fine rather than once per ball). An example:

```
setInterval(function () {
 balls.forEach(a=>a.animate());
 context.fillStyle = "white";
 context.fillRect(0, 0, w, h);
 balls.forEach(a=>a.draw());
}, 30);
```

Add this inside your render function after your for loop.